# Angular: ngFor is not updated for new items

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 4 to build an app that displays a list of books with title, description and their rating as hearts like the following:

```
<h2>{{book.title}} <small *ngFor="let h of hearts">❤</small></h2>
```

In order to get the right number of hearts I created this getter

```
get hearts() {
  if (this.book.rating < 0) {
    return new Array(0);
  } 

  return new Array(this.book.rating);
}
```

For the initial set of books this works quite well. But when I add a new item to the array of books only one heart is displayed. All the other properties however are set correctly. As soon as I change something, also the hearts get updated and are displayed correctly.

Any guesses what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is quite inefficient. A method or getter bound to in the components template will be called every time change detection is run. If it returns a new object instance (array instance in your case), Angular will get the impression that the value never stops changing. This should even cause an error like "Expression has changed ..." and performance of your app will be horrible. Instead assign the result of the getter to a field and bind to the fields to avoid this issue, and only update the field after the content of the array actually changed.

Comment: It looks like a change detection problem. what change detection strategy you are using. you can manually make a push as well add `private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef` and then `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();` where you need it

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might have to do with the component LifeCycle.  It's possible that the template gets built before your data gets finished loading...(before book.rating value is set).  You could try putting a call to get hearts inside an ngOnInit() method to make sure it gets refreshed.

Also, Deborah Korata has a very interesting way of showing a "5 star" rating for product listings in her course called "Angular: Getting Started" on Pluralsight. (http://www.pluralsight.com).  She put the rating inside it's own component.  And then puts it in as a select tag:

```
<star-rating></star-rating>
```

The component template looks like this:

```
<div class="crop" [style.width.px]="starWidth" [title]="rating">
    <div style="width: 86px">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The cool thing about this approach is that it actually can show half stars / percentages of stars instead of just whole stars for ratings that are 3.5 or the like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<small *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5].slice(5-book.rating)">❤</small>
```

Comment: While this code might work, it's far better to explain how or why this is a solution.

Comment: small explanation: * ngFor works on arrays. We create an array "on fly" and remove the first characters (length of the array minus desired number). So, i.e., if the desired number is 3, we eliminate (5-3 = 2 characters) and our array will be [3,4,5]